# How can I connect my Windows application with a program that runs on localhost

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm developing an application that is for the Windows store. The application has buttons that send you to a couple of domains.

```
private IDictionary<string, string> environments = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
            {"DEMO", "https://somedomain.com"},
        };
        
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        
public void navigateToDemo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine( this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AppView), environments["DEMO"]) );
        }
```

I want to test some changes of one of the pages that the user can be sent to, but I want to test the changes instantly, not having to deploy a whole new version just to see some small change.

When I change the URL to the localhost, the page doesn't load anymore...

How can I do this?

Comment: What makes you confident that just replacing the URLs with localhost URLs will work? Have you tried using those localhost URLs in a web browser on the same machine? (That should be pretty much the very first troubleshooting step to see whether the webserver on localhost is actually correctly set up and running)

Comment: The localhost URLs work correctly on web browsers, that's why I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Are the localhost urls http or https?

Comment: make sure you changed https to http and try writing not just localhost but localhost:80 or whatever port the webpage loads on, if it won't help try changinng environments

Comment: The localhost is http. The port Is included in the string too. :(